# I want to parse a txt file and place it into a struct

Tags: c++, parsing, struct

I have a text file containing info with the following format:

> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA_SSSSSSSSSSSSSS_111_999999
>        BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB_TTTTTTTTTTTTTT_111_999999

I want to be able to parse it in c++ with the `_` as a delimiter and store it so that it can be accessed later on.

My plan is to create a struct like this:

```
struct fileContents{
    string text1;
    string text2;
    int num1;
    int num2;
};
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: You're looking at the right track but you need to start walking down it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I agree with you.

then you implement some function like this/

```
struct fileContens parseString(string input/or your text file stream){

}
```

the return type is struct, and you will assign the each part to each element in the struct.

Comment: That works but it would be better to implement an extractor for the class.

Comment: yea, I agree. To follow the principle that "one does one thing but does well", this function can sit inside your "extractor"